# MediaExtractor causes SIGABRT on getTrackFormat()

Tags: android, android-ndk

Inside my audio player app I need to extract the meta information of audio files prior to playing them. Playback is handled using `MediaCodec` and `MediaExtractor` inside Java. Target level is API 16, NDK is also used for some custom C code.

On some platforms (especially Samsungs with Android 4.x) the app crashes when trying to get a `MediaFormat` by using `MediaFormat.getTrackFormat()` on some special file types - e.g. it happens on a .m4a container with an ALAC audio track (I **know** that this is an unsupported file type for Android but still I do not want my App to crash when trying to read out the `MediaFormat`, even if it's a non-sense / bogus file)

The root cause is that `libstagefright` chokes on the input format because it's not able to read the meta information from the file, causing an `SIGABRT` and the app crashes.

My first thought was that this is most likely an assertion failure, but it's more subtle as it ultimately is related to logging.

Digging deeper I found that the initial "assert failure" is triggered by the `CHECK` macro inside [`Utils.cpp`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/android-4.4.2_r2/media/libstagefright/Utils.cpp#107) due to missing channel count information. In the end this leads to [LOG_ALWAYS_FATAL_IF](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-4.4.2_r1/include/log/log.h#374) which ultimately brings the app down.

As my app also uses some native C code and the NDK I already tried to set `NDEBUG` et. al. but then realized that this will only affect my code but not any precompiled code deployed on the target.

Also, I tried to run the `MediaFormat.getTrackFormat()` in a background Thread spawned by the main UI Thread but the `SIGABRT` kils my App's process and not just the background thread from where the call originated from.

Btw, this happens both in debug and in release builds.

Is there any way to get around the `SIGABRT` being raised so it does not kill my App?

PS: Rooting the device or updating the Android OS version is **not** an option.

Comment: Further thinking about this makes me wonder if this is actually the same bug/issue that led to to notorious "Stagefright Exploit" which means there is no real way to workaround it.